Can you tell a good e-reader to buy in India?
I am buying an e-reader in India, and I found the following popular e-readers:

Kobo
Kindle
Onyx Boox

Did anyone buy these? Can you tell me how to buy them in India?
Some of them need to be imported and don't have repair services.
Open to advice.

Hi, and welcome to Stack Exchange! Do you have any specific requirements for your e-reader? Price, features, backlight, color, battery life, types/sources of books you'll be reading, etc.?

Hey, this is my first time buying an e-reader, and I would like an explicit guide on how to buy one.

It’s difficult to provide a truly comprehensive guide covering all use cases; usually such questions are too broad for us to answer effectively. Do you have any specific requirements, such as those I listed before?

I will be reading all genres of books, academic textbooks, newspapers, RSS feeds and articles. ( medium, substack )

It should be a colour e-reader.
Minimum battery life of more than a day.
I think the backlight is there by default
the screen should be rotatable and left-hand and right-hand friendly. I would like some rough note-taking with a stylus.

I have no idea about the price and features.
I have the following models in mind.


kobo libra colour


onyx go color 7
Is Bigmee a good brand?


